# Text widget multi line isn't working and giving an error

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a multi line Text widget. Here's the code I have:

```
return Card(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/myImage.jpg'),
            width: 150,
          ),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[Text(
                    'some loooooong Text hereeeeeeeeeeee some loooooong Text hereeeeeeeeeeee',
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    maxLines: 5,
                  ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

For some reason it's not working, i.e. it isn't multi-line, and it's giving the error of:

> RenderFlex overflowed by 9.0 pixels on the right.

I tried wrapping the `Text` widget around an `Expanded` and a `Flexible` widget, but I then the following error:

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints
> are unbounded

Comment: Why do you have a `Column` with a single child?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore No, the Column contains 2 text widgets and 1 row widget.

Comment: And you're not showing them in the code? I was just wondering the purpose of that. Also share some context of what's going on higher in the tree. Is there a scroll view or stack of some sort that's not providing constraints? Either way, you should have wrapped the whole column in `Expanded`, not just the `Text` widget. For the most part, you want text to expand horizontally. The purpose of `Expanded` is just to provide constraints to the text so it knows where to wrap, while giving it the most room possible. You could alternatively wrap it in a container or sized box with constraints.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I didn't add the code here since I only wanted to put the relevant code, which I guess I made a mistake on what was relevant :) Thanks sooo much for the answer! Wrapping the column in expanded did the trick! Can you post as an answers so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap the whole `Column` in `Expanded`, not just the Text widget. For the most part, you want text to expand horizontally. The purpose of `Expanded` is just to provide constraints to the text so it knows where to wrap, while giving it the most room possible. You could alternatively wrap it in a `Container` or `SizedBox` with constraints.

```dart
return Card(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/myImage.jpg'),
            width: 150,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[Text(
                      'some loooooong Text hereeeeeeeeeeee some loooooong Text hereeeeeeeeeeee',
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      maxLines: 5,
                    ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```